# Oracle SQL loop through the same data and base it on the current date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm trying to select the same data multiple times with oracle SQL based on the date.

For example at the moment I wrote this SQL query to calculate my balance at the current date:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY') date,
(
select (   
            select NVL(sum(bedrag), 0) bedrag
                from transactie 
                where rekening_naar_id = r.id
                and datum <= sysdate
                and actief = 1

        )  
        -  
        (
            select NVL(sum(bedrag), 0) bedrag
                from transactie 
                where rekening_van_id = r.id
                and datum <= sysdate
                and actief = 1
        ) 
    from dual     
    ) 
as balance
from rekening r
where r.id = 2;
```

I was wondering if its possible to loop trough this same data multiple times in a single SQL query and select multiple rows just increasing the date by 1 day every time? The balance is changing based on the date to show in a chart.

I can't use PL/SQL for this query because I need the data to be filled in a Oracle Apex chart and there is no option to use PL/SQL to generate the chart. Only a valid SQL query or PL/SQL code which returns a valid SQL query is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you think "loop in Oracle SQL", think `connect by level`.

This example goes 30 days into the future.

```
select d.date1,
(
select (   
            select NVL(sum(bedrag), 0) bedrag
                from transactie 
                where rekening_naar_id = r.id
                and datum <= d.date1
                and actief = 1

        )  
        -  
        (
            select NVL(sum(bedrag), 0) bedrag
                from transactie 
                where rekening_van_id = r.id
                and datum <= d.date1
                and actief = 1
        ) 
    from dual     
    ) 
as balance
from rekening r
cross join (select trunc(sysdate+(level-1)) as date1
    from dual
    connect by level < 31) d
where r.id = 2;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/832a73/1)

A **cross join** is the same as a plain `join my_table` with no join conditions, or  `join my_table on 1=1`. It returns all combinations of the rows in both tables. In this case, it returns all combinations of rows in `rekening` with rows in the *inline view* named `d` (which contains dates for the next 30 days). Try running the `d` view's select statement by itself to see what it does.

```
select trunc(sysdate+(level-1)) as date1
from dual
connect by level < 31;
```

**Connect by level** is a special case of the hierarchical `connect by` clause. It generates a sequence of rows/numbers, which can be very useful. Here's a very simple example:

```
select level from dual connect by level < 10;
```

Comment: Thanks alot this seems to work! Could you explain the cross join and connect by level? I don't really understand how the query works.

Comment: Sure, I edited the answer with more details. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: I understand the query now! Thanks again. Always fun to learn new things :-)